# Angular restfull call in plnkr 404

Tags: angularjs

Im trying to connect to the openweather api using a factory function in angular. However I get an 404. My link is spot on, but I guess its failing because of the plnkr code in front of the api link

```
GET http://run.plnkr.co/65ULuFbF2mV8fL2X/api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=London 404 (Not Found)
```

The test file can be found here:
http://plnkr.co/edit/wstR9oZdYf24jxjru8vS?p=preview

Is there some kind of code or setting to remove the `http://run.plnkr.co/65ULuFbF2mV8fL2X/` from the call?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CORS (Cross Origin Resource Sharing) is not supported by the OpenWeatherMap api.

You can take a look at this article to see the reason your code doesn't work: [accessing-external-apis-with-angularjs](http://arunisrael.com/2013/08/25/accessing-external-apis-with-angularjs.html)

> This means that the OpenWeatherMap API does support CORS. We can try
>   to access the API via JSONP. $http.jsonp on an API that does not
>   support CORS, but supports JSONP

I updated your plunker to make it work:

in CONSTANTS.js

```
LINK:  'http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q='
```

in weatherFactory.js

```
$http.jsonp(config.LINK + city + "&callback=JSON_CALLBACK")
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/jTYDQlytgIx3jUXQa4MD?p=preview